# Why do we need the regularization term for NMF but not for SVD?

Tags: regularization, svd, matrix-decomposition, non-negative-matrix-factorization

In non-negative matrix factorization (NMF) one minimizes the Frobenius norm plus a regularization term. However SVD simply minimizes the Frobenius norm. Why do we need the regularization term for NMF but not for SVD?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NMF does not always include regularization -- for example, see the first two cost functions [here](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1861-algorithms-for-non-negative-matrix-factorization.pdf). But, regularized NMF can be useful:

- If you're willing to add extra constraints beyond nonnegativity, you can produce highly interpretable structures, [including the K-means centroids](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~hpark/papers/GT-CSE-08-01.pdf).
- If you want to fit an NMF so that $X = LR$ where $L$ is wider than $X$, the model is useless (trivial, ill-posed, non-identifiable) because you could just set $L$ equal to a zero-padded version of $X$ and set $R$ to a zero-padded identity matrix. In this case, an L1 penalty on each factor matrix will help out by encouraging both factors to contribute. For a low-dimensional example, a pair of 3's incurs a lower L1 penalty than a 9 and a 1.

Another possible answer is that SVD is a rigid term and NMF is not. If you added regularization to an SVD, it would no longer be called an SVD, but the term NMF is less prescriptive.

Comment: NMF is quite often used with the objective function only defined for observed values. That is with a large number of missing values in the matrix.  Is it related to that ?

Comment: Amazingly, the low-rank structure [works pretty well](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.0467) on its own.